# Using Object Result to receive a query (stored procedure) in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Data (FormCollection form)
{
    int qId = Convert.ToInt32(form["EmailAddress"].ToString());

    using  (var db = new AdventureWorks2014Entities() )
    {
        ObjectResult<GetEmail_Result> em = db.GetEmail(qId);       //error
    }
    //more code downwards
```

This is the error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult'
>   to
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult'

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: You can try `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<GetEmail_Result> em = db.GetEmail(qId);`

Comment: You seem to be mixing EF5 and EF6

Comment: What do I do purely for entity framework 6?